# C# how to add elements to a xml file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm using WinForms .NET 2.0 for my application. Previously, I used NET 4.0 to add an element to an existing XML file in this way:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(spath);
        XElement root = new XElement("Snippet");
        root.Add(new XAttribute("name", name.Text));
        root.Add(new XElement("SnippetCode", code.Text));
        doc.Element("Snippets").Add(root);
        doc.Save(spath);
```

Where spath is the path of the XML file. I am having trouble degrading this code to .NET 2.0 since the syntax is confusing, can someone help me? I'm trying to add an element with an attribute and element like this:

```
<Snippet name="snippet name">
    <SnippetCode>
    code goes here
    </SnippetCode>
  </Snippet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(spath);
XmlNode snippet = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Snippet", null);

XmlAttribute att = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
att.Value = name.Text;
snippet.Attributes.Append(att);

XmlNode snippetCode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "SnippetCode", null);
snippetCode.InnerText = code.Text;

snippet.AppendChild(snippetCode);

doc.SelectSingleNode("//Snippets").AppendChild(snippet);
```